# Iterator execution hangs after the iterator is exhausted

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator

I have a generator function that takes **iterator** object and performs some logic on every item. This runs on a larger list of iterations. It then **yields** the result back to the calling code, so it can break the `for` and `while` loop

```
def func(it):
    item = next(it)
    item = item.execute()
    yield item

it = iter(range(1, 10))

condition = True
while condition:
    for item in func(it):
        condition = item
        print condition
```

Executing this code in Python IDLE, prints the follows and **hangs:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I need to CTRL+C to break out the loops. If I use regular **range(10)** so the loop starts with the value 0, it breaks immediately (since `condition=0`) and return prompt.

What am I missing? Why my iterator hangs when exhausted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator isn't the one hanging, it's your `while` loop. Since `condition` ends at `9`, the while loop becomes `while 9` which never exits. Take out the while loop completely.

```
for item in func(it):
    condition = item
    print condition
```

Or, if you want to stop if the condition is false, then:

```
for item in func(it):
    condition = item
    print condition
    if not condition: break
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is not hanging. The outer while loop is. You have set it to run forever as condition changes from 1-9 and then remains as 9. So, code executes to:

```
while 9
```

which always returns True and this becomes an infinite loop.